# Isolating the first word of a string

Tags: python

This is the code i've wrote so far:

```
def first_word(text: str) -> str:
    while text.find(' ') == 0:
       text = text[1:]
    while text.find('.') == 0:
        text = text[1:]
    while text.find(' ') == 0:
        text = text[1:]
    while text.find('.') == 0:
        text = text[1:]
    if text.find('.') != -1:
        text = text.split('.')
    elif text.find(',') != -1:
        text = text.split(',')
    elif text.find(' ') != -1:
        text = text.split(' ')
    text = text[0]
    return text
```

it's supposed to isolate the first word in a string, it shold delete any ".", " ", "," and keep only the word itself.

Comment: look into regex and replace functions

Comment: You can use regex , and select the first match. 
Example https://pythex.org/?regex=%5Cw%2B&test_string=testing%2Calkjasdsfs&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sentence="bl.a, bla bla"
first_word=first_word.replace(".","").replace(",","")
first_word=sentence.split(" ")[0]
print(first_word)
```

Or you could try a list comprehension:

```
sentence="bl.a, bla bla"
first_word=''.join([e for e in first_word if e not in ".,"]) #or any other punctuation
first_word=sentence.split(" ")[0]
print(first_word)
```

Comment: There is an easier way to do this, but for this method you can chain `replace()` instead of assigning at each step.

Comment: Thanks added that :) I wanted to use replace() instead of regex since it does not require knowing regular expressions.

Comment: while this is much better than what i was using, it does not work with stuff like `... bla bla`.

Comment: Would you even consider ... to be a word? and in that case you can just use the replace() first before doing the split()

Answer (score 2):

Using `re`, and `split()`:

```
import re
ss = 'ba&*(*seball is fun'
print(''.join(re.findall(r'(\w+)', ss.split()[0])))
```

Output:

```
baseball
```